Replicating hkdf2 key derivation in C
I am trying to create a derived key from my shared secret and shared key. I have done this before, in Java and Python, where it is a fairly straight forward process, however, it seems that in C this requires a few more steps.
Here is my working Java code:
    HKDFBytesGenerator hkdf2 = new HKDFBytesGenerator(digest);
    hkdf2.init(new HKDFParameters(sharedSecret, mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey, info));

    byte[] sharedKey = new byte[48];
    hkdf2.generateBytes(sharedKey, 0, sharedKey.length);

Where info is:
[-63, 20, 124, -15, -40, -14, -53, 23, 15, 24, -38, 39, 34, 28, -43, 47, 46, 37, 107, -15, 4, -92, -117, -45, 75, -7, -35, -80, -82, 78, 109, 95, -38, 40, -5, -123, 85, -79, 33, -96, 17, -86, 106, -121, -17, -52, -7, -111, -77, 11, 105, -117, 110, 12, -87, 19, 44, -74, 58, 95, 87, -98, -90, 19, 2, 13, 76, 41, 3, 44, 54, 4, 76, -11, 27, -82, 70, -107, -1, 36, -114, 41, -46, 122, -60, -111, -111, -14, -105, -85, -113, -74, 118, 7, -127, -100, 115, 37, -13, 71, -113, 48, 68, 2, 32, 83, -33, 54, -35, -77, 4, -95, -55, -128, -66, 126, -46, -23, -43, -63, -41, 66, 92, 104, 85, -19, 113, 85, -9, 95, -97, -4, -58, 89, 88, -76, -36, 2, 32, 119, -73, 86, -9, -45, 21, -66, -56, -101, -107, 118, -78, 51, -48, -118, 91, -14, 51, -40, -115, -7, -5, 58, -60, -75, 22, 29, 40, 13, -110, 94, 36]

mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey is:
[3, -13, 114, -79, -98, 38, 121, -52, -109, -35, 111, 100, 43, 78, -96, 42, -28, -32, -75, -87, 83, 22, -22, -105, 69, -109, 47, -23, 127, -62, -128, -109, -99]

And sharedSecret:
[-27, -24, -42, 64, 23, 20, 36, 24, 46, 45, 57, -60, -53, 5, 106, 82, -128, -126, 66, 62, 42, -60, -72, -75, -90, -38, 54, -97, 98, -67, 29, 59]

And as a result my sharedKey is
-85, 26, -57, -120, -55, -12, 58, 22, -36, -86, 40, -21, -69, -109, -86, 2, 2, 26, 87, 97, 51, -56, -16, -71, 95, -115, 9, -45, -98, 125, 35, -12, 100, 41, -68, -68, 9, -40, 43, 74, 108, 27, -101, -98, -67, 85, 119, -108
My broken C code is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/kdf.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

void set_error(char **error, const char *message) {
   if (error != NULL) {
       if (*error == NULL) {
           *error = strdup(message);
       }
   }
}

void concatenateByteArrays(unsigned char *result, int *result_len, unsigned char *arrays[], const int lengths[], int num_arrays) {
   int pos = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < num_arrays; i++) {
       memcpy(result + pos, arrays[i], lengths[i]);
       pos += lengths[i];
   }
   *result_len = pos;
}

unsigned char *extractSharedKey(
   unsigned char *mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey, int mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey_len,
   unsigned char *terminalNonce, int terminalNonce_len,
   unsigned char *mobileDeviceNonce, int mobileDeviceNonce_len,
   unsigned char *collectorId, int collectorId_len,
   unsigned char *terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed, int terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed_len,
   unsigned char *signedData, int signedData_len,
   unsigned char *sharedSecret, int sharedSecret_len,
   int sharedKey_len, // Added parameter to specify the desired key length
   char **error)
{
EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_HKDF, NULL);
if (!pctx) {
    set_error(error, "Failed to create HKDF context");
    return NULL;
}

   unsigned char info[1024]; // Ensure this buffer is large enough for your data.
   int info_len;
   unsigned char *arrays[] = {
       terminalNonce, mobileDeviceNonce, collectorId,
       terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed, signedData
   };
   int lengths[] = {
       terminalNonce_len, mobileDeviceNonce_len, collectorId_len,
       terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed_len, signedData_len
   };

   // Concatenate the arrays into 'info'
   concatenateByteArrays(info, &info_len, arrays, lengths, 5);

   printf("Info: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < info_len; i++) {
       printf("%02x ", info[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   
   // Allocate memory for the shared key
   unsigned char *sharedKey = (unsigned char *)malloc(sharedKey_len);
   if (sharedKey == NULL) {
       set_error(error, "Failed to allocate memory for shared key");
       return NULL;
   }

   printf("mobile key: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey_len; i++) {
       printf("%02x ", mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey[i]);
   }

   printf("\n");
   printf("shared secret: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < sharedSecret_len; i++) {
       printf("%02x ", sharedSecret[i]);
   }
   if (EVP_PKEY_derive_init(pctx) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "Failed to initialize HKDF");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

   if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_md(pctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "Failed to set HKDF hash function");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

   if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set1_hkdf_salt(pctx, mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey, mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey_len) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "Failed to set HKDF salt");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

   if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set1_hkdf_key(pctx, sharedSecret, sharedSecret_len) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "Failed to set HKDF key");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

   if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_add1_hkdf_info(pctx, info, info_len) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "Failed to add HKDF info");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

  printf("Derived shared key: ");
   for (int i = 0; i < sharedKey_len; i++) {
       printf("%02x ", sharedKey[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   printf("Shared key length: %zu\n", sharedKey_len);

   printf("pctx: %p\n", pctx);
   if (EVP_PKEY_derive(pctx, sharedKey, &sharedKey_len) <= 0) {
       ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
       set_error(error, "HKDF operation failed");
       EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
       free(sharedKey);
       return NULL;
   }

   EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);
   return sharedKey; // Return the derived shared key
}

EC_KEY* getPublicKeyFromBytes(const unsigned char* pubKeyBytes, size_t length, char** error) {
   EC_KEY* key = NULL;
   EC_POINT* point = NULL;
   const EC_GROUP* group = NULL;

   // Initialize OpenSSL
   OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

   // Create a new EC_KEY structure for the specified curve
   key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
   if (!key) {
       set_error(error, "Error creating EC_KEY structure.");
       return NULL;
   }

   // Get the group used by the curve
   group = EC_KEY_get0_group(key);

   // Create an EC_POINT object from the bytes
   point = EC_POINT_new(group);
   if (!point) {
       set_error(error, "Error creating EC_POINT.");
       EC_KEY_free(key);
       return NULL;
   }

   if (EC_POINT_oct2point(group, point, pubKeyBytes, length, NULL) != 1) {
       set_error(error, "Error converting bytes to EC_POINT.");
       EC_POINT_free(point);
       EC_KEY_free(key);
       return NULL;
   }

   // Set the public key point in the EC_KEY structure
   if (EC_KEY_set_public_key(key, point) != 1) {
       set_error(error, "Error setting public key.");
       EC_POINT_free(point);
       EC_KEY_free(key);
       return NULL;
   }

   // Free the point object
   EC_POINT_free(point);

   // Return the created key
   return key;
}


int main() {
unsigned char mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey[] = {3, 243, 114, 177, 158, 38, 121, 204, 147, 221, 111, 100, 43, 78, 160, 42, 228, 224, 181, 169, 83, 22, 230, 151, 69, 147, 47, 233, 127, 194, 128, 147, 157};
unsigned char terminalNonce[] = {193, 20, 124, 241, 216, 242, 203, 23, 15, 24, 218, 39, 34, 28, 213, 47, 46, 37, 107, 241, 4, 164, 139, 211, 75, 249, 221, 176, 174, 78, 109, 95};
unsigned char mobileDeviceNonce[] = {218, 40, 251, 133, 85, 177, 33, 160, 17, 170, 106, 135, 239, 204, 249, 145, 179, 11, 105, 139, 110, 12, 169, 19, 44, 182, 58, 95, 87, 158, 166, 19};
unsigned char collectorId[] = {2, 13, 76, 41};
unsigned char terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed[] = {3, 44, 54, 4, 76, 245, 27, 174, 70, 149, 255, 36, 142, 41, 210, 122, 196, 145, 145, 242, 151, 171, 143, 182, 118, 7, 129, 156, 115, 37, 243, 71, 143};
unsigned char signedData[] = {48, 68, 2, 32, 83, 223, 54, 221, 179, 4, 161, 201, 128, 190, 126, 210, 233, 213, 193, 215, 66, 92, 104, 85, 237, 113, 85, 247, 95, 159, 252, 198, 89, 88, 180, 220, 2, 32, 119, 183, 86, 247, 211, 21, 190, 200, 155, 149, 118, 178, 51, 208, 138, 91, 242, 51, 216, 141, 249, 251, 58, 196, 181, 22, 29, 40, 13, 146, 94, 36};
unsigned char sharedSecret[] = {229, 232, 214, 64, 23, 20, 36, 24, 46, 45, 57, 196, 203, 5, 106, 82, 128, 130, 66, 62, 42, 196, 184, 181, 166, 218, 54, 159, 98, 189, 29, 59};
   char *error = NULL;
   int sharedKeyLen = 48; // Desired length of the shared key
   unsigned char *sharedKey = extractSharedKey(
       mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey, sizeof(mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey),
       terminalNonce, sizeof(terminalNonce),
       mobileDeviceNonce, sizeof(mobileDeviceNonce),
       collectorId, sizeof(collectorId),
       terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed, sizeof(terminalEphemeralPublicKeyCompressed),
       signedData, sizeof(signedData),
       sharedSecret, sizeof(sharedSecret),
       sharedKeyLen, &error);

   if (sharedKey) {
       printf("Shared Key: ");
       for (int i = 0; i < sharedKeyLen; i++) {
           printf("%02X", sharedKey[i]);
       }
       printf("\n");
       free(sharedKey); // Free the allocated memory for the shared key
   } else {
       printf("Error extracting shared key: %s\n", error);
       free(error); // Free the allocated memory for the error message
   }

   return 0;
}


However, I get the error "HKDF operation failed". Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I've spent a while trying to crack this 

I cannot reproduce the issue. On my machine I get the same result that is generated by the Java code (for identical input parameters). However, the posted C code is not complete, so I had to add the missing parts. It is possible that the bug is in these parts. So please post a complete, executable code including initialization with the test data (mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey, sharedSecret, info), see MCVE.

For instance, how did you generate pctx? E.g. EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id() in combination with an incorrect ID can result in an HKDF operation failed.

Hi @Topaco, I've updated my code so you can see it in it's entirety now. Hopefully this helps. Are you able to show the code that you got working?

The newly posted code works on my machine as well, I can't reproduce your error message. However, it produces a different result than the original code. This is due to a mismatch in mobileDeviceEphemeralPublicKey. The old code had the value -22 (or 234) at index 22, while the new code has the value 230 (or -26). If this is fixed, the result of the old code is returned. Apart from this data discrepancy, I cannot find any problem.

What version of openssl?

Interesting, I'm confused why it's not working on my end then. I'm using I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.3.0/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.3.0/lib -lcrypto @Allan Wind

@Topaco what version of openSSL did you use?

I have tested with OpenSSL 3.2.1 [30 Jan 2024].

What do you recommend if this problem persists? I've realised I can't downgrade my OpenSSL using homebrew

The code also works for me with OpenSSL 3.3.1 [4 Jun 2024]. I am not convinced that it is a general problem with 3.3.0. You may not have OpenSSL installed properly or there may be some incompatibility issue in your environment.

Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it! Just to be clear, you didnt change the code at all to get this result, and you ran a command like: gcc -o extractsharedkeys extractsharedkeys.c -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.3.1/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.3.1/lib -lcrypto? I'll look into my environment

I'm on Windows and using the MS C/C++ compiler and not the GNU complier/GCC. The posted code is run unchanged (except for getPublicKeyFromBytes(), which is not needed for the test).

I suggest you compare a working solution with a non-working one and inspect the partial data along the way.  Consider using inttypes.h instead of native types.  You are missing a #include <string.h> and define_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L .  You use %zu to print sharedKey_len but it's a %ul.  On my system EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name, EC_KEY_get0_group, EC_KEY_free gives deprecation warnings.

... ‘EVP_PKEY_derive' expects a size_t *but you pass in aunsigned long *`.

Don't cast the void * (from malloc()) in C.  It's required in C++.

In extractSharedKey() I see you malloc sharedKey it but don't see it being initialized before printing the "Derived shared key".  What am I missing?

Please revise question and include actual output of your program (instead of editorializing it).  You probably want to print a newline after printing the shared secret.

I made all the changes you suggested and it now works!! Thanks alot @AllanWind
